# How can i check login page redirect in all pages in php

Tags: javascript, php, html, mysql

My Index pages work in perfect. but the same time directly call home page mean its open.

I want if any page call check login. already login mean go to that page. Or else go to login page.

any body give the coding for login session.

**This my my login code**

```
<?php
session_start();
include 'connect.php';
if(isset($_POST['validate']))
{
    $username = mysqli_real_escape_string($mysqli,$_POST['username']);
    $pass = mysqli_real_escape_string($mysqli,$_POST['password']);
    $sel_user = " select * from user where username='$username' AND password='$pass'";
    $run_user = mysqli_query($mysqli, $sel_user);
    $check_user = mysqli_num_rows($run_user);
    if($check_user>0)
    {
        $_SESSION['user_name']=$username;
        echo "<script>window.open('home.php','_self')</script>";
    }
    else
    {
        echo "<script>alert('Email or password is not correct, try again!')   </script>";
        echo "<script>window.open('index.php','_self')</script>";
    }
}
```

?>

Comment: I have try for this code but not working
<?php
session_start();
if(!isset($_SESSION['username']))
{
    $_SESSION['loc'] = "home.php";
    header("location:home.php");
    exit();
}
    ?>

Answer (score 1):

You are starting a session without checking username and password. also the password should be hashed. Be aware of sql injection. use prepared statements.

```
<?php
include 'connect.php';
if(isset($_POST['validate']))
{
    $username = mysqli_real_escape_string($mysqli,$_POST['username']);
    $pass = mysqli_real_escape_string($mysqli,$_POST['password']);
    $sel_user = " select * from user where username='$username' AND password='$pass'";
    $run_user = mysqli_query($mysqli, $sel_user);
    $check_user = mysqli_num_rows($run_user);
    if($check_user>0)
    {       
            session_start();
            $_SESSION['logged_in'] = true;
            session_regenerate_id(true);
            header("Location:home.php");

    }
    else
    {
        echo "<script>alert('Email or password is not correct, try again!')   </script>";
        echo "<script>window.open('index.php','_self')</script>";
    }
}
```

To check if already logged in or not in any page add this code:

```
session_start();
if(!$_SESSION['logged_in']){
 session_destroy();
 header("Location: login.php");
```

Comment: I WANT HOME PAGE ALSO CHECK WITH LOGIN OR NOT

Comment: you could add this to check if user is logged in or not.: if(!$_SESSION['logged_in']){
 session_destroy();
 header("Location: inputnow.php");

Comment: But above given code user name show on 1. Before user name correctly display it. and directly call home page it was went. 

If user not logged in call home page mean go to login page.

Comment: you can add this to display user name: $_SESSION['user_name']=$username;

Comment: Sorry Mr Sanzeeb aryal 
This code put top of home page.
always come in login page only.
Like proper login also not go for home page.

Comment: Yes. you need to login to enter the homepage. or what  are you wanting?

Comment: I have call directly in home.php  page mean it will go for login page.
because security purpose.

Comment: plain password itself is not secure at all.

Comment: No no. i have call at home page mean just check login or not. If login mean go to home page. or else go to login page.
Then logging after go to home page. that all
don t except plain password.

Comment: you can start a session in homepage too. session_start();

Comment: see my updated answer at last. this should solve your issue.

Comment: That coding home page redirect but not opened.

This error showing my browser
This webpage has a redirect loop

ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS

Comment: Please note that the preferred way of saying 'thanks' around here is by   accepting the answer by clicking the check-mark.This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution. There is no obligation to do this.